# Setting hyperlink programmatically

Tags: c#, datagridview, hyperlink

Using c# winforms

EMP | NAME | CERT | DATE | FILE

I want to set a column to allow me to click on a cell and read the hyperlink which it can if the data in the cell is like D:\ms.jpg. The problem now is that I want to set it to a specific directory and the file name would change based on the other cells. The prefix would be 'D:\Tim\Cert\' and the rest of it would be values in the other cells like {EMP} {(Name)}{CERT} {(DATE)}.pdf (for e.g. '1234 (Tim)\Maths (25-4-2016).pdf') I know about System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() but can you customize it to allow what I want or is it fixed only to read variables?

```
        private void LoadData()  
        {
//others
            for (int intCount = 0; intCount < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; intCount++)      //-----------------hyperlink
        DataGridViewCell cell = (DataGridViewCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

        if (cell.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["FILE"].Index)
        {
            DataGridViewLinkCell hl = (DataGridViewLinkCell)         //-----------------hyperlink
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            string filepath = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filepath);
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing since the hyperlink shouldn't be in other columns
        }
         }
```

Comment: What do you mean by fixed to only read variables? Process.Start does expect a /parameter/ if that's what you're asking.

Comment: By fixed variables I mean like if theres a variable pic = "D:\Tim\Cert\pic.jpg" then can I use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(picture) to open the file?